# Setting JPA behavior for importing entities from tables

Tags: jpa

How can I tell JPA how to behave with different column types in my database when it tries to generate the entities from tables?

[image]

For example when I have a column like the following in my MySQL:

```sql
`deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

I want in the generated entity by JPA have `boolean` instead of `byte`, but what the JPA will generate is something like this:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private byte deleted;
```

However I want to have something like this:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private boolean deleted;
```

I think there must be a way that I tell JPA how to translate the column types in my tables in the entities in Java!?

*I don't like to modify the entities by hand!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last page of that wizard we can define the expected type for each column. The interesting part is, eclipse stores somehow the selected types for each column and in the future when you try to regenerate the entities you don't need to do this step times to times!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to configure the *Eclipse wizard* to map `TINYINT` onto `boolean`, the answer is you probably cannot.

Using [Hibernate tools](https://o7planning.org/en/10125/using-hibernate-tools-generate-entity-classes-from-tables) looks more promising, though. There's a [hibernate.reveng.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html#type_map) config file you can use to control type mapping.

As a side note:

> I don't like to modify the entities by hand!

Note that reverse engineering tools in general lack the business knowledge required to generate a business model structure that is completely sensible. You will likely have to do *some* tweaking (e.g you likely won't get any `@ManyToMany` associations, even if they are the more natural solution domain-wise).